# How to list all stored WiFi information even if I have turn off WiFi

Tags: android

I can use the following code to get a list of all wifi information I have connected, but I can't get the right list information if I turn off my phone WIFI.

I think the connected wifi information have been stored in disk, no matter turn on or trun off WiFi, I should get all wifi information I have connected, right? Thanks!

```
public String ListStoredWiFi(Context context) {

    String textStatus = "";
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);     

    // List stored networks
    List<WifiConfiguration> configs = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

    if (configs!=null){     
      for (WifiConfiguration config : configs) {
          textStatus += "\n\n" +config.SSID+" CW "+config.networkId;
      }
    }

    return textStatus;
}
```